# Magento 2 custom shipping method hide/show on basis of city

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

I want to show/hide custom shipping method like "*Delivery in 2 hours*" radio button if customer fills particular city on checkout page. If he is from that city will show "*2 hour delivery*" option if not will hide it.
Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help, but finally I solved the issue, getting postal code from Ajax and finding city on the basis of the postal code and then manipulating shipping option.

Thanks and Cheers

Ali

Comment: hey @ali how you did this please post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [M2 Shipping Module](https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping-setting) helped me manipulate the shipping methods to suit my needs. I built to exclude delivery to certain postcodes and also use a custom attribute to set the method's price.

---

update (in light of question)

I guess it needs to install properly first but based on your question you might look at modifying something like these suggestions from the [documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping-setting/blob/master/view/doc_en_US.html)

```
addMethod('id_005', [
    'title'      => "France, Germany, Switzerland, Spain, Italy",
    'enabled'    => in_array($request->dest_country_id, ['FR', 'DE', 'CH', 'ES', 'IT']),
    'price'      => 10,
]);
addMethod('id_006', [
    'title'      => "Postcode starting with 25",
    'enabled'    => $request->dest_country_id == 'FR' && substr($request->dest_postcode, 0, 2) == '25',
    'price'      => 10,
]);
addMethod('id_007', [
    'title'      => "Regular expressions allowing postal codes beginning with 'PO' (case insensitive)",
    'enabled'    => $request->dest_country_id == 'GB' && preg_match('/^PO.*$/i', $request->dest_postcode),
    'price'      => 10,
]);
```

Comment: I tried this module, but I think this is not working fine it throwing error when I installed it. it would be great if you could share your module

Comment: see my updated answer. hope it helps put you on the right path.

Comment: I installed this module, but when I logged into my admin panel and went under stores-configuration-sales-shipping method the page become blank

Comment: It gives this error Fatal error: Class 'Owebia\AdvancedSettingCore\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\AbstractField' not found in /var/www/testproject/punamdhote/Magento2Site/app/code/Owebia/AdvancedShippingSetting/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/About.php on line 9

Comment: sorry mate, i cannot comment on errors like these. maybe try going back to Owebia direct or look through their github issues (open and closed)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit corresponding shipping class and add city validation, something like this:

```
/**
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return bool|Result
 */
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($request->getDestCity() != 'Minsk') { // add your city validation here
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier('shipping');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('shipping');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

Previous code works if you want to remove the whole carrier with all methods. If you want to remove just one method you should add a validation before calling of the `append($method)` method:

```
if ($method->getMethod() == 'your_method_code') { // validate method
    if ($request->getDestCity() == 'Minsk') { // validate city
        $result->append($method);
    }
} else {
    $result->append($method);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I would like to ask that in $request how city will come? if user has not fill the city field on checkout form?

Comment: Also $request->getDestCity() always remain empty when I logged it into log file

Comment: @AliFani which shipping method you are using?

Comment: I have created custom shipping method and gave title "2 hour delivery", I want it to show based on shipping address, in both guest customer and logged in customer

Comment: @AliFani Could you share your code?

Comment: I get city when I click on Next, but during filling the form I am not getting the city    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {      $cityFinal=$request->getDestCity();